# Question about maximal orthonormal subset in infinite dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthonormal

The question is this:

> Let $A$ be an orthonormal subset of vectors in an infinite dimensional vector space $V$. Suppose for every $0\neq y \in V-A$ there is a $v \in A$ so that $\langle v,y \rangle \neq 0$. Show that $A$ is then a maximal orthonormal subset of $V$.

So in trying to prove this I have run into a number of "uncertainties":

1. I suppose such a subset $A$ need not be finite? A maximal orthonormal subset need not be finite? Could it even be that $A$ is not countable?
2. Let's say we have an orthonormal subset $A$, and we can find a normal vector $w \in V-A$ so that $A \cup \{w\}$ is linearly independent. Can we say \begin{equation} u=w-\sum_{v \in A}\langle v,w \rangle v \end{equation} is orthogonal to every vector in $A$ (in other words apply Gram-Schmidt to turn $A \cup {w}$ into an orthonormal subset). Does this depend at all on whether $A$ is finite/countable, or does Gram-Schmidt "work" regardless.

Any confirmation/counter-examples would be much appreciated...also any suggestions for another approach to proving this would be much appreciated. The question is (part of) a question from "The linear algebra a beginning graduate student ought to know" by Golan (the converse is straightforward).

Comment: What does *orthogonal* mean here, exactly? It seems you're not working in a plain vector space here, but rather in some inner product space. So what kind of inner product are we talking about? In particular, does it turn $V$ into a hilbert space? (For that, the innert product must be hermitian and positive definit, and $V$ must be complete as a normed space, where the norm is induced by the inner product). If that is the case, some form of gram-schmidth should work, but you still need to be carefull with that sum - it must converge!

Comment: @fgp Sorry in the title, should be orthonormal (I edited it just now)...but to the best of my knowledge from the textbook, it is an inner product space, but not necessarily a Hilbert space. What the book does mention is that a maximal orthonormal subset is known as a Hilbert subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for every **y** in V -A  there is at least one element **v** of A such that $\langle v,y \rangle \neq 0$ then then there is no vector **y** in V -A which is orthogonal to every vector in A.

Therefore A is maximal.

Comment: Haha, well duh, I confused maximal and maximum...of course, you are right...I was trying to prove that $A$ is the maximum orthonormal subset by comparing it to other maximal orthonormal subsets...quite a feat (and maybe not attainable?). Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Ek se dis die taal se fout.

Comment: absoluut ja ;))